# Is NamedParameterJdbcTemplate vulnerable safe?

Tags: sql, spring, postgresql, security, sql-injection

We are  using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate to achieve "IN" operator functionality.
Is there any SQL Injection vulnerability when we use NamedParameterJdbcTemplate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` internally use `PreparedStatement` for querying , and if you can make sure that you do not build the SQL query by somehow  concatenating the input from the user , but using the  placeholder `:xxxx` to specify their value, it should prevent SQL injection as the query and the data entered by the user are sent to the DB separately.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8265319/339637) for the details about why it can prevent SQL injection thanks to such separation.

Comment: Thanks and we are using as placeholder only.

Comment: @ArjuPidugu Glad to hear . So consider to accept or vote up my answer please?